# Kruskal naive implementation: how to use DFS to detect cycle in MST plus next edge?

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree, depth-first-search

Most discussion of naive (without Union-Find) implementations of Kruskal's algorithm for finding the minimal spanning tree that I see has a handwavy bit: "just use DFS to detect if there is a cycle" and then moves on to more optimised approaches.

I like to understand problems so I'm not interested in just skipping to the union find implementation, but I am struggling with some implementation details:

At each iteration I need to consult the edges from all of the nodes in my MST and find the minimum edge that ends in the unvisited notes, then check if there is a cycle.

To use DFS do I now need a third data structure (graph of MST + new edge) to send to my `cycle_detect` routine?

- it seems like constructing this will be expensive because I'll have to go through my nodes in MST and only copy edges that are in the tree
- at other stages of the algorithm I do need to consider edges that are not in the MST, so I can't work with only the MST edges throughout

This is enough to make myself think that I'm missing something about this. Perhaps the problem is my implementation of the rest of Kruskal's algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but to see if an edge (u,v) would create a cycle, you can run a DFS from u and check if it reaches v. You do not add the edge before doing that, only after (and only in the case the DFS doesn't reach v, i.e. adding the edge doesn't create a cycle).

Comment: @Tassle would that be a DFS from `u`, only searching the edges that are in the MST? Or searching all edges from `u` regardless of where they are in the MST? If the former then it seems like we need a copy of u with all edges adjacent and a copy of u with only edges in the MST. That's the sort of confusion I'm thinking through.

Comment: A DFS through the edges which are currently included in your (partial) MST. You can either have a second graph which starts empty and is built up progressively untill you get an MST (your suggestion I think) or have an attribute on the edges of the full graph describing if they are currently chosen or not. Then you just toggle that attribute to "true" when choosing an edge to include in the MST.